# graph theory with 2017 vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a connected graph of $2017$ vertices, each of them of degree $100$.
 I have to prove that $E$
can be decomposed into [stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(graph_theory)) of $50$ edges. Suggestions?

Comment: ... stars do not satisfy the criterion that every vertex has degree $100$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein: so? I guess you may pick the same vertex as the center of two different stars, or some vertex as the center of a star, and the remaining 50 edges from such vertex as rays of stars centered elsewhere. It is $E$ we have to decompose, not $G$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I see. Your answer is good, though I suspect OP could've benefited from having to clarify the meaning of the question - it's quite hard to attempt to answer a question when you don't even know what's being asked.

Answer (score 4):

It is enough to show we may give an orientation to each edge, in such a way that at each vertex the number of ingoing/outgoing edges is the same. Then each vertex, together with its $50$ outgoing edges, provide  a decomposition of $E$ in stars with $50$ edges.

Since $G$ is connected and any vertex $v_1,\ldots,v_{2017}$ of $G$ has even degree, $G$ admits an [Eulerian circuit](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerianCycle.html). We may choose an orientation for the edges of such Eulerian circuit: clockwise or counterclockwise, it does not matter.

At the end of this process every edge of the original graph has an orientation, and every vertex has the same number of ingoing/outgoing edges since in every simple circuit every vertex has exactly one ingoing and one outgoing edge. $\square$

[image]

In this diagram we have a $4$-regular graph on $9$ vertices, and we may clearly see how the Eulerian circuit $1-18$ induces a decomposition of $E$ in $18$ stars with two rays each.